# Are there different methods I can do for onBackPressed ()?

Tags: android, onbackpressed

Are there different methods I can do for OnBackPressed ()? Or any other method that could solve my problem. I drew the problem as a picture, because I think it would be better to explain it with painting.

```
public class BarcodeReaderFragment extends Fragment  {



        @Override
        public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
            final SparseArray<Barcode> qrcode = detections.getDetectedItems();
            if (qrcode.size() != 0) {
                Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                vibrator.vibrate(150);
                Intent my = new Intent(getActivity(),ResultActivity.class);
                my.putExtra("type", qrcode.valueAt(0));
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                String json = gson.toJson(qrcode.valueAt(0));
                SharedPreferences sp = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("list",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                addhistory(sp,json);
                startActivity(my);
                getActivity().finish();
                barcodeDetector.release();


        }
        }
```

}

```
public class ResultActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent my = new Intent(ResultActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(my);
    finish();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

}

```
public class ThreeFragment extends Fragment {



public void action(int i){
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    SharedPreferences sp = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("list", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String temp =  sp.getString(String.valueOf(i),"");
    final Barcode b1 = gson.fromJson(temp,Barcode.class);
    Intent my = new Intent(getActivity(), ResultActivity.class);
    my.putExtra("type",b1);
    startActivity(my);


}
```

}

[image: My problem is like in the picture]

Comment: What are you wanting to do?

Comment: I switch from three fragments to result activity and then I cannot return.  As I described in the picture.